# How to run simple jdbc connection program through cmd

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Below approach I tried to run and compil
for compile:

```
javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc.jar" OracleTest.java
```

for execution:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc.jar;." OracleTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: getting below error:                               
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: remove the doublequotes arround the cp arguments

Comment: If I run the command without double quotes I am getting below error          javac: invalid flag: Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: add doublequotes arround one entry not the whole string: -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin";"D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc"

Comment: while compilation I did not get any error but when try to run got this error , see below command and error                                                java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin";"D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc.jar" OracleTest
Error: Could not find or load main class OracleTest

Comment: has OracleTest a main method? Please share the code

Comment: yes..Its running fine in eclipse.getting error only outside eclipse.

Comment: import java.sql.*;  
class OracleTest{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{    
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@199.158.1.555:1521:rakesh","user","pass");  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MR_USER_INFO WHERE  LOWER(USER_ID) = LOWER('RAM') AND LOWER(PASSWORD) = LOWER('ravan')");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+""+rs.getString(2));  
con.close();  
 }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
 }  
}

Comment: Any package declarations?

Comment: see the code..there is no package declaration.

Comment: is the class file in the actual Directory?

Comment: Of course..I am not changing directory to run the command. using same directory for javac and java

Comment: Then add the actual directory to your classpath

Comment: not getting you..I have java file in D directory and executing javac and java  from D directory only and its also generating .class file in D directory.

Comment: java -cp .\,"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin";D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc.jar; OracleTest

Comment: No luck..getting error                                                                                      D:\>java -cp .\,"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin";D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc.jar; OracleTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Sorry the first `,` in the classpath should be a `;`

Comment: Should I add .\; while compilation(javac) also..or only in java

Comment: No it is not necessary there

Comment: No luck again...Anyway Thank you so much!! for your valuable time.

Comment: are you sure the driver file is named "ojdbc.jar" and not something like "ojdbc**7**.jar"?

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC drivers from oracle usually include a (Java) version number in the name like `ojdbc14.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar`. I do not have Oracle installed here, so please check the correct name in your directory `D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\`.

You can test my DBTester program I wrote a long time ago from [here](http://simu.wikidot.com/java:dbtester). After downloading the jar - eventually you need to rename `DBTester.jar.zip` to `DBTester.jar` - just execute it in the directory you saved the jar:

```
java -cp "DBTester.jar;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\jdb‌​c\lib\ojdbc7.jar" cfh.dbtester.Main -d
```

(assuming the ojdbc7.jar is the driver file and using Java 7 or later)

This should print a summary for some drivers, including the Oracle one, like

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver OK
```

the last line is telling me that I have the OracleDriver available.

Note: DBTester.jar creates a file named `dbtester.log` with its results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this?

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -cp  "%~dp0\ojdbc.jar" OracleTest.java
```

Important thing to note here is to have the `JAR` file at the same location as of your `JAVA` class that you want to compile/execute and accordingly change the command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is this..%~dp0...should I leave it as it is.

Comment: You can use it as is!